# creating textbox element dynamically and bind different model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working in angular js application, where i need to create textbox with buttons dynamically that means

```
<div class="col-sm-4 type7" style="font-size:14px;">
    <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">NDC9</div>
        <input type="text" name="ndc9" class="form-control txtBoxEdit" ng-model="ndc9">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 type7 " style="font-size:14px;">
    <div style="padding-top:20px; display:block"> 
        <span class="red" id="delete" ng-class="{'disabled' : 'true'}">Delete</span> &nbsp; <span>Cancel </span> &nbsp;  <span id="addRow" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="ndcCheck(0)">Add </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

this will create below one

[image]

i will enter some value in above textbox  and click add ,it needs to be created in next line with same set of controls that means  (textbox with above 3 buttons need to be created again with the entered value).

1. Entering 123 in first textbox and click add will create new textbox with delete,cancel,add button with entered value.
2. Again am adding new value 243 then  again it needs to create new textbox down to next line with the entered value (and also the same controls).

finally i want to get all the entered values. how can i achieve this in angular js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ng-repeat with an associative array. Add Would basically push the model value to an array and and also an empty object in the array.

```
<div ng-repeat ="ndc in NDCarray">
    <div class="col-sm-4 type7" style="font-size:14px;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">NDC9</div>
            <input type="text" name="ndc9" class="form-control txtBoxEdit" ng-model="ndc.val">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 type7 " style="font-size:14px;">
        <div style="padding-top:20px; display:block"> 
            <span class="red" id="delete" ng-class="{'disabled' : 'true'}" ng-click="NDCdelete($index)">Delete</span> &nbsp; 
            <span>Cancel </span> &nbsp;  
            <span id="addRow" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="NDCadd ()">Add </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.NDCarray = [{val: ''}];

$scope.NDCadd = function() {
    $scope.NDCarray.unshift(
        {val: ''}
    );
};

$scope.NDCdelete = function(index) {
    $scope.NDCarray.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/3lklQ6ADn9gArCDYw2Op?p=preview

Comment: how it will work for initial element. initially i want all 3 controls need to be there. when i click add then that time again i have create same set of controls ? will it work in that case ?.. please make it in fddle

Comment: Are you dynamically loading the html as well? See the update to answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!!

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
    <title>Directives</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('exampleApp', [])
            .controller('defaultCtrl', function () {
                vm = this;
                vm.numbers = [1, 2, 3];
                vm.add = function (number) {
                    vm.numbers.push(number);
                }
                vm.remove = function (number) {
                    var index = vm.numbers.indexOf(number);
                    if(index>-1){
                         vm.numbers.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="num in vm.numbers">
        <span>Number : {{num}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" ng-model="vm.newNumber">
        <button ng-click="vm.add(vm.newNumber)">Add</button>
        <button ng-click="vm.remove(vm.newNumber)">Remove</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```